# Doctrine QueryBuilder summary functions in Symfony entity repositories?

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony, query-builder

Is there a way I can use `min()` (or equivalent) in Doctrine's QueryBuilder?

The page I'm working on shows a table of invoices for the current (or impersonated) user. It has a row for each of their invoices and has nested collapsible rows of any associated payments (see below image)

My issue is that in my twig template I need to be able to be identify at the Invoice-level if any of it's Payments have not been approved. If any payment is not approved then I need to flag both the payment and the Invoice row it relates to. For example, in the below example, "Invoice #1" is yellow because it has a nested "Payment #2" record that is yellow (not approved):

[image: Invoice/Payment image]

To get access to this at the Invoice-level I have been trying to do it through my InvoiceRepository but I'm unclear if/how this can be done using QueryBuilder. I somehow need `anyToBeApproved` (which isn't an attribute of my Invoice entity) to be available, and still have the Payment information also included:

```
select a.*, min(b.approved) as anyToBeApproved
from Invoice a
left join Payment b
on a.invoice_id=b.id
where a.member_id=$Uid
group by a.id
```

### My controller:

```
$invoices = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Invoice')->OutstandingForUser($this->getUser()->getId());
```

### My QueryBuilder:

```
public function OutstandingForUser($Uid)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('i')
        ->select('i')
        ->leftJoin('i.member_id','m')
        ->leftJoin('i.payment_ids','p')
        ->andwhere('m.member_id = :MemberId' )
        ->setParameter('MemberId',$Uid)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why this hasn't been answered yet, but you should be able to use those aggregate functions just fine.

> The following aggregate functions are allowed in SELECT and GROUP BY
>   clauses: AVG, COUNT, MIN, MAX, SUM

See the documentation: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#aggregate-functions

You can use aggregate functions inside of querybuilder ->select() OK.

I'd rewrite your function as something like:

```
public function OutstandingForUser($Uid)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('i')
        ->select('i, min(p.approved) as anyToBeApproved')
        ->leftJoin('i.member','m', 'WITH', 'm.member_id = :MemberId') // this works better with not actually constraining your left join, otherwise you might as well just use innerJoin
        ->leftJoin('i.payment','p') 
        ->groupBy('i.id')
        ->setParameter('MemberId',$Uid)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

**Here's an alternative approach, given you seem to want all the invoice rows anyway.**

Change your fetch function to:

```
public function OutstandingForUser($Uid)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('i')
        ->select('i, p, m') // may as well pre-fetch all entities
        ->join('i.member','m') // member is surely mandatory? so no left join required
        ->leftJoin('i.payment','p') // payments may not be present, so left join
        ->where('m.member_id = :MemberId')
        ->setParameter('MemberId',$Uid)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

Then in your invoice entity do something like

```
    public function hasUnapprovedPayments () {

        foreach ($this->getPayments() as $payment) {

            if (!$payment->approved()) {

                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function hasPayments () {

        return !$this->getPayments()->isEmpty(); // assuming doctrine collection
    }
```

These functions will be pretty fast as you have already hydrated the entities in the function above.

You could also add a similar isFullyPaid method that loops through payments, but I would personally make that a bool or datetime on Invoice that is set when the invoice is completely paid.

Then in twig you can do stuff like:

```
    {% for invoice in invoices %}
      {% if invoice.hasUnapprovedPayments %} do something {% endif %}
      {% if invoice.hasPayments %} do something {% endif %}
      {# loop through all your payments etc #}
    {% endfor %}
```

Which should make it pretty easy to get the layout you want.

Comment: Thanks very much - I've updated my QueryBuilder as you said and the `min()` is being added to the Invoice row - but the Payment rows are getting "grouped" out. I've tried `->GroupBy('i.id','p.id')` but unfortunately this does not work either. Do you know how I need to adjust it?

Comment: Sounds like you would have to always fetch each invoice anyway. I have added an alternative approach for you as I'd solve the problem myself.

Comment: Awesome - thank you very much! The entity functions are a great idea :)